# How to use input selector in multiple places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, keyboard

I am running virtual keyboard plugin in my input box addon. I am using two different input one is bottom of the page and another one is using popup. I have to split the script in two different ways. Now the same keyboard calling for both input.

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-20">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="" class="search_field form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon key-show"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mt-10">   
    <div class="keyboard show-allkey" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
$('.keyboard').jkeyboard({

  layout: "english",
  input: $('.search_field')
});
```

My demo url : https://rawgit.com/saravanasksp/jkeyboard/master/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the link (https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-On-Screen-Visual-Keyboard-with-jQuery-jkeyboard.html) provided by you,

We need to keep a **keyboard div** adjacent to the **input** we need to connect the plugin with.

To implement keyboard with two inputs at two different locations you have to place two different **keyboard div** with **unique identifier(class or id)**. Then initialise these two keyboards with two different inputs.

For better explanation I have mentioned the example code below:-

```js
//For 1st location or 1st input
$('#keyboard1').jkeyboard({
  layout: "english",
  input: $('#input1')
});

//For 2nd location or the modal
$('#keyboard2').jkeyboard({
  layout: "english",
  input: $('#input2')
});
```

```html
<!-- Location1 -->
<input type="text" id="input1">
<div id="keyboard1"></div>

<!-- Location2 or Modal -->
<input type="text" id="input2">
<div id="keyboard2"></div>
```

Comment on it if you feel any doubt.

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-On-Screen-Visual-Keyboard-with-jQuery-jkeyboard.html

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example code for your question

Comment: When I use multiple input filed more than 5 how ? every time I need to use id="keyboard1,2,3,4,5................

Comment: As per document it seems so. Else you can try to write a custom code to select elements with class and inside that assign each element with the given code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differantiate those two inputs giving them different id's.

```
<input id="input1".....>

$('.keyboard').jkeyboard({
  layout: "english",
  input: $('#input1')
});
```

Comment: No. have to use multiple places in the same input box